# Galois group of $(x^2-2)(x^3-2)(x^3-3)$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to find the Galois group of $(x^2-2)(x^3-2)(x^3-3)$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$. The roots of this polynomial are $\pm \sqrt{2}$, $\zeta_3^k \sqrt[3]{2}$, and $\zeta_3^j \sqrt[3]{3}$ for $j,k=0,1,2$, so that the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \zeta_3)$.

Can someone help me find:

1. The Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$
2. The Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$